# Evaluate a selected number of cells in a matrix

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix `M` and like to use a selected number of cells in other computations. For example, given a matrix `M`:

```
M={{2,4,1},{3,2,0},{4,0,1}};
```

I like to scan all of its elements using index `[i,j]` and exclude those cells with `i=j` (diagonals), for example, from the subsequent computations.

Here is a MWE:

```
n = 3;
a1 = Array[2 &, {n, n}];
a2 = {};
Do[
 If[i != j, AppendTo[a2, a1[[i, j]]], 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}
 ];

a2={4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0};
```

and got `a2`. It does what I want, however, this `code` does not look efficient, takes much space in the entire code and creates variables which will not be used again.

Is there any way to just `scan` the matrix `M` and pick the cells of interest for subsequent use without creating extra variables?

Comment: `Drop[Flatten@M, {1, -1, 4}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Flatten @ ReplacePart[M, {n_, n_} -> Nothing]
```

Or, probably faster for bigger `M`:

```
Flatten @ Pick[M, IdentityMatrix@Length@M, 0]
```

Comment: I works but it also replaces `Nothing` as a text element of the list created. Can my `Mathematica v 10.0.2.0` be the reason for this? If so, is there any other way to get around this problem. I do not want `Nothing` as an element of the final list  created. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Yes, `Nothing` is new in 10.4 so you would need to use `Sequence[]` for example.

Comment: May I ask you how to use `Sequence` in my example?. Your answer work fine and thank you very much for very quick answer.

Comment: `Pick[M, IdentityMatrix@Length@M, 0]` would be simpler.

Comment: @CarlWoll well, sure. I don't know what was I thinking :)

Answer (score 8):

```
Flatten @ MapIndexed[Drop, M]
```

> {4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0}

Comment: Sorry if my question is very simple. How does your `code` recognize that cells with `i=j` are dropped from the list?  and if I want to create the list of upper diagonal elements, how would you apply your `code`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose `MapIndexed` is a built-in function recognizing the cells with `i=j`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, `MapIndexed[Drop, M]`  drops the kth alement from the kth row (it may be easier to see what is happening by inspecting `MapIndexed[{#,#2}&, M]` and `MapIndexed[foo, M]`) . For elements strictly above the diagonal, you can use `Flatten@MapIndexed[Drop[#, #2[[1]]] &, M]`

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification. My problem is solved for now:)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses `ArrayRules` to associate each element with its indices, and then pick out the one you want using `Cases`. I use a `Unique` symbol as a default for `ArrayRules` so you get an explicit rule for every element; otherwise `Cases` won't grab all the elements you want:

```
Cases[ArrayRules[M, Unique[]], 
 HoldPattern[{i_, j_} -> a_] /; i != j :> a]
(* {4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0} *)
```

Here's a fairly efficient way of doing it with procedural code, using `Sow`/`Reap`.

```
Reap[
  With[{n = Length@M},
   Do[If[i != j, Sow@M[[i, j]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]] /.
{{Null, {result_}} :> result,
 {Null, {}} :> {}}
```

Here's a compiled procedural version that should be fast that's almost like yours, but avoids `AppendTo`, which is generally bad news (and I don't think will even compile).

```
compiled =
     Compile[{{matrix, _Real, 2}},
  Module[{
     m, n,
     result,
     fill = 0,
    },
    {m, n} = Dimensions[matrix];
    result = ConstantArray[0., m*n];

    Do[If[i != j, result[[++fill]] = matrix[[i, j]]], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];
    Take[result, fill]]];
 compiled[M]
 (* {4., 1., 3., 0., 4., 0.} *)
```

Because the function is compiled and I assumed the type of the matrix was real, everything got returned as a machine real.

Comment: Thank you for this overwhelming `code`.  Since you developed this code, you might want to show it with an example matrix with dimension `(6,6,2)`. For example, you may show how to delete `diagonal elements and the last 2 columns` from this example matrix. This will be a very useful piece for me.